# mahapps.metro with ExcelDNA not working

Tags: mahapps.metro, excel-dna

Posting here to see if any mahapps.metro experts might have an idea.  Let me know if 'cross posting' is bad form.  (Or if you want me to replicate my post here)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/exceldna/POi8EYfXsOE

**Update**: I created a repo as asked at https://github.com/terryaney/ExcelDNAMahappsDebug

The strange thing was, when I recreated problem here the window appeared correct, so I don't know what I did different.  I then tried to create the window again in my real project and was able to create the window AGAIN correctly.

I guess my question now is (and maybe you don't have to look at repository, not sure) is:  How come the window in *design time* doesn't look like a mahapps.metro window?  (note, this is my first xaml/wpf effort).

Comment: It would be nice you can show us your hole implementation (you can put it on GitHub), so we can debug it and maybe help you with this issue :-D

Answer (score 0):

As my update states, it seems to work after I re-implemented it.